# Language switch doesn't work for a specific application (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-layout, language-support

Since recently I'm unable to enter text input into Chrome in any layout except English, despite switching keyboard layout and having the correct input language indicator.
This behavior is specific to Chrome only, since I'm able to enter non English characters in any other applications that I've tested.

I'm using Ubuntu 18:04
Linux 5.3.0-20-generic #21+system76~1572310493~18.04~b3805b2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 29 01:5 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Chrome version: Version 79.0.3945.16 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Update:
The issue is limited to the beta version of Chrome, but not to a specific profile. Reported the issue to Google.

Comment: Same on Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 with Chrome 79.0.3945.16 (Official Build) beta (64-bit). Even if I restart Chrome, it always uses the English layout.

Comment: It's fixed in 80.0.3987.16! Yay! Thanks for reporting this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its an extension issue.  Does the problem exist in incognito mode?

```
google-chrome-beta --incognito
```

Comment: Tested for incognito mode and guest profile, got the same results. I think it's a Chrome bug that they introduced in the latest update.

Comment: Another weird symptom: it fill passwords in the correct layout.

Comment: You could switch to stable channel.

Comment: It's a definite workaround. Hopeful that they'll fix it before it reaches the stable channel. Will test later on a Windows machine, whether this bug is platform specific.

Comment: If switching to stable resolves the issue than you could report the bug for the beta version.